# How do I implement function _getch without using the standard library?

Tags: c++

Without using the standard library, how can I get the input character in the console, and after obtaining the input character, the character will not be displayed in the console?
Similar to the function "_getch" in the header file conio.h

I tried looking for related functions in the Windows API, but I didn't find them

Comment: What _do_ you have? The question isn't tagged Windows, but you hint at it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput

Answer (score 0):

There is no function for that, you would have to rewrite the functionality of getch(), which would involve a combination of assembly and syscalls.